# Servus mitanand?

Tags: vocabulary, dialect, austrian, bavarian

What does **Servus mitanand** mean? I have looked at Google and can not find any translation of this phrase. I know that **servus** is kind of greeting.

But what does the phrase mean and what is the origin?

Comment: *mitanand* = *miteinander*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general meaning is "Hi, everybody!".

*Servus* is a greeting that is common in Austria and Bavaria (see [A strange greeting! Servos?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6728) for more details); the other word is a dialectal form of *miteinander*, here indicating that you are addressing a group.

Similar greetings that are less bound to a specific region:

> Hallo zusammen!
>   Hallo allerseits!