# Der Ursprung der Begrüßung "Seas"

Tags: grammar, dialect

> Seas! Wie geht es dir?
>
> Mir geht es sehr gut und selber?
>
> Auch sehr gut, danke!

Woher kommt das Wort "Seas"? Einige Deutschen, mit denen ich spreche, sagen es anstatt eines "Servus". Ist das die Abkürzung davon?

Comment: Ich habe mit ihnen auf Interpals geredet.

Comment: Weißt Du, wo sie herkommen?

Comment: Ich habe mit einem aus Österreich u dem anderen aus Bayern gesprochen. Nicht alle kennen es.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eindeutig ein verschleiftes "Servus".

Answer (score 5):

Das Wort »servus« ist lateinisch und heißt auf Deutsch: Sklave, Diener, Knecht.

Zum Gruß (wenn man sich begegnet) wurde dieses Wort vor allem in Österreich in der Bedeutung »Ich bin dein Diener«. Ich Österreich war auch die deutsche Übersetzung »g'schamster Diener« in Verwendung (heute eher selten benutzt). Die Etymologie von »g'schamster« ist umstritten, standarddeutsch heißt das Wort aber »untertänigster« oder »gehorsamster«. Also »gehorsamer Diener«.

Gebräuchlicher war und ist aber der Gruß »Servus«, der sich später auch als Gruß für Verabschiedungen etabliert hat.

In der Umgangssprache wird »Servus« aber nicht mit einem »*u*« in der Endsilbe ausgesprochen, sondern fast immer mit einem »*a*« (wie das »*a*« in Wasser), also: »serwas«. Das »*r*« in der ersten Silbe wird ohnehin auch in der standarddeutschen Aussprache durch einen Schwa-Laut wiedergegeben, ist also ohnehin dem »*a*« recht ähnlich. Daher klingt die österreichische Aussprache eher wie »seawas«.

Das »*w*« wiederum wird zwischen den beiden a's gern verschliffen und verschluckt, also weggelassen: »sea'as«. Die dadurch entstehende Zäsur erleidet aber dasselbe Schicksal wie das »*w*«, und so werden die beiden a's zu einem:

Seas!

Comment: Das ist es, was ich gedacht hab :)

Answer (score 1):

Seas sagt man bei uns in Oberösterreich anstatt Servus, ist Mundart. Das Gegenteil davon ist übrigens Pfiat Di oder Tschüss.