# Kontextunterschied bei Tschüss und bei einem langen ausgesprochenen Tschüss?

Tags: meaning, question, low-german, context

ich habe von einem Freund die Frage gestellt bekommen, warum man manchmal ein einfaches "Tschüss" zu oder ein lang ausgesprochenes "Tschüss" sagt. Mir ist das bis jetzt kaum aufgefallen, da ich auch meist das zweisilbige "Tschüss" automatisch verwende. Nur letztens habe ich beim Abschied von einer mir bekannten Person sogar ein noch längeres Tschüss gehört ("Tschüüüüss") und aus diesem Kontext heraus stelle ich mir die Frage ob es irgendwie einen Unterschied macht? Z.B. kontextbezogen (also z.B. fremde Person, aus Höflichkeit oder vllt. sogar Sympathie etc.) und wenn ja:  Wann könnte man welches angemessenerweise verwenden?

Comment: I'm thinking this type of thing isn't specific to German; in English you can use a short "bye" or a two-syllable "by-ee". While the two are by no means interchangeable, I'd hate to try to explain the difference.

Comment: Ich würde zur sichtbaren Unterscheidung "Tschüss" für das kurze und "Tschühüss" für das lange schreiben. So wie jetzt fällt es mir schwer, den Unterschied beim Lesen im Kopf zu machen.

Comment: Wenn du in Österreich (oder auch in Bayern) bist, solltest du mit "Tschüss" zurückhaltend sein. Hier ist "Servus" die bessere Wahl. Siehe: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/62511/1487

Comment: Related:https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/tsch%C3%BCs-aussprache-tsch%C3%BC-%C3%BCs/

Answer (score 2):

Aus meiner persönlichen Erfahrung als Wiener würde ich sagen, dass man das kurze "Tschüss" als Verabschiedung im kleinen Kreis in normaler Gesprächslautstärke verwendet. Das längere und lauter ausgesprochene "Tschüühüüs" würde ich eher dann verwenden, wenn ich mich zum Beispiel vom Büro auf den Weg nach Hause mache und alle Kollegen im Raum damit ansprechen möchte.

Wenn ich höflich sein will oder einer mir fremden Person gegenüberstehe, verwende ich keine der beiden Varianten. "Tschüss" hat meinem Empfinden nach  einen sehr informellen Charakter.

Comment: Also würdest du in deinem Fall das lange Tschüss nicht einfach zu einer einzelnen Person sagen, die du beispielsweise auf der Straße triffst  und auch kennst (auch wenn du mit ihr nicht viel zu tun hast), sondern das kurze Tschüss? Und das lange eben wenn du mehrere Personen ansprichst?

Comment: Wenn ich mich gedanklich in diese Situation hineinversetze, würde ich mich so verhalten. Eventuell würde ich das lange Tschüss verwenden, wenn zum Beispiel gerade die Straßenbahn vorbei fährt und ich mich durch den Lärm hindurch verständlich machen wollte.

Answer (score 2):

Ich [OstSüdMittel-D] empfinde jegliche Dehnung und Stauchung von Begrüßungen informeller Art/"außerhalb eines Protokolls" (z.B. Staatsempfänge) als Ausdruck von Emotionen und Gefühlen. Sowohl meine als auch dem/der/den Anderen gegenüber.

D.h., es kommt auf jeden Fall zur sinnvollen Deutung noch Betonung/Intonation/Situationskontext dazu. "[Der](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der_Ton_macht_die_Musik) Ton [macht](http://www.sprichwort-plattform.org/sp/Der%20Ton%20macht%20die%20Musik) die [Musik](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7EDer%20Ton%20macht%20die%20Musik&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)".

Eine simple Unterscheidung "nahe Freunde" = "Tschühüß" und "ferne Bekannte" = "Tschüss" greift für mich viel zu kurz.

Ergo kann ich jemand wildfremden, der mir grad den Weg erklärt hat, ein fröhliches Lang-Tschüss hinträllern - weil ich grad unglaublich gut drauf bin. Genauso kann ich meinem Partner ein frostiges ultrakurz-Tschüss "hinwerfen", weil ich grad sehr schlechte Laune habe - während ultrakurz auch nur heißen kann "bin in Eile". Oder ich mache "gute Miene zum bösen Spiel" und verabschiede jemanden lang/kurz, um gezielt aufzuheitern oder abzukanzeln.

Daher kann "je kürzer desto unbekannter" bei mir bestenfalls als spontane Daumenregel gelten.

Answer (score 1):

Ein einsilbiges "Tschüss" wird als barsch und unfreundlich empfunden. Entsprechend dem Diktum, dass "jaja" "leck mich am Arsch" heiße, heißt ein einsilbiges "Tschüss" soviel wie "Du bist mir egal." Man verwendet es, wenn man sich von Menschen verabschiedet, für die man sich nicht interessiert (wie den Verkäufer oder den Schaffner) oder auf die man böse ist (wie auf seinen egoistischen Freund) und denen man das zeigen will.

Wer Zuneigung und Sympathie ausdrücken möchte, verwendet in der Regel mehrsilbige oder gedehnte Verabschiedungen (wie "Auf Wiedersehen" oder eben "Tschühühss" oder "Tschahau"), die sich emotional intonieren lassen. Man kann sich die Bedeutung von "Tschühüss" am besten vergegenwärtigen, wenn man es sich zur Satzmelodie von "Ich mag dich" oder "Ich freu mich" gesprochen vorstellt.

*Herkunft: Schwaben*