# What does the phrase "noch viele Grüße" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read it in a letter where the girl was signing it off. The rough idea I get but I want to know what does the extra 'noch' do to the overall meaning of this fragment.

Answer (score 3):

The `noch` is a shortening of `auch noch`, which literally means `additionally`.

In spoken language, it is used, when a talk is cut short: There wasn't time to talk extensively about the person concerned. But the person should at least be greeted, so the greetings are "added" to the end of the talk.

I haven't seen it used in a letter and wouldn't do so, because it looks as a PS with important content. One get's the impression that the writer didn't think about the letter in before hand or had to short cut the letter due to time limitations.

Comment: Isn't it rather the same as with [schönen Tag noch](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7501/1224)?!

Comment: The `noch` referred to in your link is a synonym of `weiterhin` as expressed in Koivo's answer there. This wouldn't make any sense here. As the greetings couldn't be continued (indefinitely).